# Struts1 Action Parameters Use and Working

Tags: struts

I am new to Struts and I Don't Understand Struts Action Parameters, specifcally: **Name,Validate,Input** and **Redirect="true"**

Example:

```
*@struts.action name="activation" path="/activation" validate="false" parameter="activation"

*@struts.action-forward name="activationStart" path="/activation.html" redirect="true"
```

Please try to answer me in terms of above example.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you refuse to read the Struts 1 documentation?

**`name`**

The name of the ActionForm bean for this action.

**`validate`**

Should validation run?

**`input`**

The input page for the form, usually used to return to the form on a validation error.

**`redirect`**

When this forward is returned should it be a redirect or a forward?

Answer (score 0):

**Name** 
Name is the name of the formbean which is associated with you JSP. In your struts-config you will have something like this

```
<form-beans>
<form-bean
  name="activation">
<form-property name="name" type="java.lang.String"/>
</form-bean>
</form-beans>
```

**validate**
You have validator framework which has some validations in place, like checking the name field for null value and so. You tell your struts whether the validator should work or not. If `validation=false`, then validation is not performed in your current jsp

**input**

input is the input jsp. If there are any validation errors, the execute method of the action will not get called; instead the control will go back to that ***.jsp. But you have not specified any `input` in your example

**redirect**

Whether to redirect or just forward